# Subproject does not upload to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I have a Symfony project (used as backend) that was linked with a repository on Bitbucket, in this project I installed a subproject angular 2 named frontend (theme angular downloaded from Github), when I execute `git push origin master` the frontend folder does not upload to bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you add all files (folder etc.)? Did you try `git add .` command ?

When you use `git add .` it looks at the working tree and adds all those paths to the staged changes.